# Put in a list the elements that appear in a string

Tags: python, list

I would like to create a list with elements that are present in a string, for example:

String:

```
str = "Hello World, My name is Adam"
```

List:

```
lst = ["Hello", "dog", "yellow", "Adam"]
```

The idea is to receive something like this:

```
lst2 = ["Hello", "Adam"]
```

This is what I tried:

```
if any(x in str for x in lst):
    coinc.append(x)
```

But it does not work...

Comment: What are the criteria to select words from the list?

Comment: How did you go from string "Hello World, My name is Adam" to ["Hello", "dog", "yellow", "Adam"]?  Meaning some of the words in list are not in the string.  Also, it's highly discouraged to use variable names that are builtin functions (i.e. str).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most pythonic way of doing it is like this I think

```
lst2 = [s for s in lst if s in str]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
str = "Hello World, My name is Adam"
lst = ["Hello", "dog", "yellow", "Adam"]

lst2 = []
for l in lst:
    if l in str:
        lst2.append(l)

print(lst2)
```